# Scala Array Copy looks to be working differently

Tags: arrays, scala

```
    object Solution extends App {

      val arr1 = Array(
        Array(1,2,3),
        Array(4,5,6)
      )

      var arr2 = Array.ofDim[Int](2,3)
      Array.copy(arr1,0,arr2,0,arr1.length)


      arr1(0)(1) = 23

      println(arr1.map(_.mkString(",")).mkString("\n"))
      println()
      println(arr2.map(_.mkString(",")).mkString("\n"))

    }
```

1,23,3
4,5,6

1,23,3
4,5,6

what is wrong, why is the 23 appearing in both arrays

Comment: Why not? Both `arr1` and `arr2` are referencing the same inner arrays, so when yo mutate one through `arr1` then `arr2` also changes because it doesn't has a copy of the data, just a copy of the reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array.copy` uses `System.arrayCopy` which modifies both the arrays. In the [doc](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Array$.html#copy(src:AnyRef,srcPos:Int,dest:AnyRef,destPos:Int,length:Int):Unit):

> Copy one array to another. Equivalent to Java's System.arraycopy(src, srcPos, dest, destPos, length), except that this also works for polymorphic and boxed arrays.
>
> Note that the passed-in dest array will be modified by this call.

You can try a simple `map` with `identity`:

```scala
scala> val arr1 = Array(Array(1,2,3),Array(4,5,6))
arr1: Array[Array[Int]] = Array(Array(1, 2, 3), Array(4, 5, 6))

scala> val arr3 = arr1.map(_.map(identity))
arr3: Array[Array[Int]] = Array(Array(1, 2, 3), Array(4, 5, 6))

scala> arr1(0)(1) = 23

scala> arr1
res16: Array[Array[Int]] = Array(Array(1, 23, 3), Array(4, 5, 6))

scala> arr3
res17: Array[Array[Int]] = Array(Array(1, 2, 3), Array(4, 5, 6))
```

Comment: At this point is better not to use array at all, since they are mutable and invariant. A **List** is a better default collections and if access by index is required then a **Vector** or an **ArraySeq** would be better.

Comment: or `ListBuffer`? @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez

Comment: That is still mutable so no as a general-purpose collection, but sometimes mutability is necessary or even desirable _(mainly for performance reasons)_ in those cases if well managed then yes a `ListBuffer` may be a good choice, it depends on what you know about the building logic and the kind of collection you want to build.

Answer (score 2):

Because `Array` in Scala, or if to be more precise in JVM, because of Scala interop with Java - is a **mutable** structure, and you performing shallow copy and not a deep copy. Meaning - you copying the upper structure (or top array in your case) and not entire structure recursively, like all downstream array.

Solution might look like:

```
val source = Array(
  Array(1, 2, 3),
  Array(4, 5, 6)
)

val target = Array.ofDim[Int](2, 3)

source.zipWithIndex.foreach { case (row, index) => 
  Array.copy(source(index), 0, target(index), 0, source.length)
}

target(0)(1) = 23

println(source.map(_.mkString(",")).mkString("\n"))
println()
println(target.map(_.mkString(",")).mkString("\n"))
```

which will print out result:

```
1,2,3
4,5,6
1,23,0
4,5,0
```

Scatie example: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/lrrHyGqZRxKk7mZ6CbLoiA

**UPDATE**

As correctly stated @Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez in the comment section - `zipWithIndex` expensive operation. More optimal solution would be

```
(0 until source.length).foreach { index => 
  Array.copy(source(index), 0, target(index), 0, source.length)
}
```

Comment: The `zipWithIndex` is expensive and unnecessary. Just do a `(0 to arr1.length).foreach`

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez thank you so much - I've updated the answer.